# UIViews not animating when changing between each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I have 2 views which are the same size, with colourPreview set as a subview of self.view. This is my code for showing the animation:

```
-(void)startEditingHexLabel {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{ 
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:hexTextView cache:YES];
                         [colourPreview removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.view addSubview:hexTextView];
                         [self.view sendSubviewToBack:colourPreview];



                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [hexText becomeFirstResponder];
                     }];

}
```

But it just changes to the new view without a transition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` (docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_48)). Seems this is preferred in iOS 4.0+. There's an example of how to use it in those docs.

If you want to use your current method, I think `forView` in `[UIView setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:]` needs to be the superview of the views you want to animate. In your case, this looks to be self.view. Full docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_45).

HTH